# My folders turned into files on my FAT32 usb

Tags: usb, filesystems, data-recovery, fat32

I have some very important archives in folders on my USB. I needed to use a program on a computer in my school because i did not have it in my laptop, but when i plugged and checked my USB in the computer, some folders randomly transformed into files and i do not know how to fix this. I checked back into my laptop and it was the same.

Context: both my laptop and the computer were both in Windows 10.

I tried checking the propeties to see if i could open them like a folder, but it does not let me, and i am worried that if i keep messing with the file i am going to lose all my projects.

Comment: Golden rule: Never keep the only copy of any data on something as fragile as a USB stick/SD card. They have a remarkable propensity for suddenly dying.

Comment: Save whatever you can salvage - the card is dying.

Answer (score 2):

It remains to be seen if this can be fixed somewhat automatically, this may require disk editing. Anyhow, using free tools:

- As a first step image the drive. There are many tools available that allow you to image a 'drive', DMDE is one and here's an example: https://youtu.be/32GJr39O744. Regardless the tool, you need it to produce a 'flat', non-compressed, dd-type raw disk image.
- Once you have the image file, copy it (so you have *two* disk images, experiment with one only) and try mount it using OFSMount

[image]

Untick read-only option

[image]

You now have the option to safely run chkdsk <*assigned drive letter*> /f without risking your original drive.

If chkdsk successfully repairs the file system, you can copy files from the mounted disk image.

- If OFSMount/chkdsk do not yield desired result, scan disk image using DMDE and see if files can be recovered this way.
- If not successful, a disk/hex editor may help turn files into folders again. Often you do not edit them to the extent you have a valid file system, just enough for file recovery tools to treat the folders as such again. Using DMDE:

You get there by selecting the file, right click, select 'open entry', edit menu > edit mode (cursor appears) > make desired change. Now disk > device i/o parameters > first tab, enable write. Then disk > apply changes. Now force DMDE to re-read the volume (close program and open again will work).

**This video shows the steps: https://youtu.be/ptiys5CQe7c**

**Important:**

- You can use the free version of DMDE
- Work on the disk image (see above) or if working on the disk directly at least have a disk image as backup

Of course anything is DIY-able if you put enough time into it, but realistically this may require the help of someone with extensive file system expertise. So consider the value of the data and decide if it's worth sending the drive to a data recovery specialist.